# How to determine the index of a vector with range from 1

Tags: matlab

I have a question a the way to determine the index of a vector in matlab. Let see the my problem as the figure. I have a 6 bits that includes 2 parts: red part and blue part. Size of red part is |S1| and blue part is |S2|(ex: |S1|=2 and |S2|=4). The index of original bits (6 bits) from 0 to *l* . Now, I dumplicate the red part twice time and blue part 1 time to make the below bit with index from 0 to j. Size of red part is RF1*|S1| and blue part is RF2*|S2|. (ex: RF1=2 and RF2=1). Given a index in the below bits (from 0 to j), we can determine the index l of them in the original bit by the formula in the figure.

For example, If the index of a selected information symbol is, for example, 5, we map it to 5 mod 4+2=3 (red arrow) 
[image]
However, the index of problem is from 0. As you know, the index of a vector in matlab will starts from 1. So I changes it as the below figure. My problem is that how to find index l if given index j it by matlab code using second scheme (index from 1). I done it but it looks complex

[image]

For index starts from 1, we can see that I want to map index j=6 to l=4
This is table example
[image]

This is my code

```
function l=find_index(j,S1,S2,RF1,RF2)
    if j<(RF1*S1-1)
        l=mod(j,S1);
        if l==0
            l=S1;
        end
    else 
        l=mod(j,RF2*S2)+S1 ;
        if l==0
            l=S2;
        end
    end
 end
```

Comment: Can I suggest you add some sample outputs for a bunch of different sample inputs?

Comment: Also `d` is undefined in your function...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this?

```
function l=find_index(j,S1,S2,RF1,RF2)
    if j<=(RF1*S1)
        l=mod(j-1,S1)+1;
    else 
        l=mod(j-RF1*S1-1,S2)+S1+1;
    end
 end
```

Comment: @ASantosRIberio: It looks has some problem. For example, let see the red arrow, given index j equals 6, we must map to index of l that equals 4. I checked your code it maps to mod(6-1,4)+(2*2)+1=6. I think it corrects as l=mod(j-1,S2)+S1+1

Comment: Let see the formula that maps from index j to index d. Do you think it is wrong? I think it wrong with second case that defines l=(j-RF1|S1|) mod |S2|)+|S1|. I think the correct answer must be l=(j mod |S2|)+|S1|. This is reference paper at page 9 http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~shakeel/files/Unequal%20error%20protection%20using%20Fountain%20codes%20with%20applications%20to%20video%20communication.pdf

Comment: did not understand what you meant. Giving a quick look the code above seems to solve your cases.

Comment: I just only think the formula to convert from j index to l index in the paper that is wrong. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @user3051460 the formula is correct. I had not realized that the formulas to construct the answer were provided. If you see their second case is equal to mine but starting at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `S2` is always positive is it not? Which means that `l=mod(d,RF2*S2)+S2` can never equal zero making the check that follows unnecessary. Secondly you can transform the first `mod` to include the check like so: `l=mod(d-1,S1)+1;` so putting it all togehter:

```
if j<(RF1*S1-1)
    l=mod(j-1,S1)+1;
else 
    l=mod(j,RF2*S2)+S2;
end
```

which is probably the right answer without re-examining your logic (which I could not follow). However if for some reason you really really want a one liner:

```
l= (j<(RF1*S1-1))*(mod(j-1,S1)+1) + (j>=(RF1*S1-1))*(mod(j,RF2*S2)+S2);
```

Comment: Right. S2 is bit length, so it is always positive.

Comment: I think the l=mod(j,RF2*S2)+S2;
 must be l=mod(j,RF2*S2)+S1;
This is reference paper. Let see the pape 9 in http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~shakeel/files/Unequal%20error%20protection%20using%20Fountain%20codes%20with%20applications%20to%20video%20communication.pdf

Comment: @user3051460 I assumed your code was correct and that you just wanted to refactor. If you have problems with your logic, then I must say that I do not find your explanation or images clear at all. I suggest you add example inputs and output to your question...

Comment: Yes, Dan. This is example of original figure that index from 0.For example, If the index of a selected information symbol is, for example, 5, we map it to 5 mod 4+2=3 (red arrow). For index starts from 1, we can see that I want to map index j=6 to l=4

Comment: Add a table of sample inputs with their calculated outputs to your question

Comment: Firstly it looks like you're trying to map `l=4` to `j=6`, not `j=6` to `l=4` like you've just said (based on the direction of the arrow). So your code becomes very confusing because you're finding `l` based on `j`... So did you mislabel the diagram?

Comment: Sorry, the diagram only explains how to dumplicate from original bit to virual bits (j). And in my code, I try to map it from virual bit to original bit (l)